# Как в Jenkins пропускать сборку тех компонент которые не изменялись?

Tags: jenkins

Есть несколько проектов и есть Jenkinsfile, в котором описаны шаги (сборка проектов, деплой). На данный момент при коммите в один из проектов, последовательно пересобираются все проекты, что долго по времени. Можно ли как-то пропускать сборку тех компонент, в которые не делался коммит / те которые не изменялись?

Comment: связать job-ы условиями типа «выполнить эту job-у, когда обновится та job-а» можно огромным количеством plugin-ов (в базовую функциональность, насколько я знаю, это не входит). какой из plugin-ов у вас используется (и как настроен) — вы не упомянули. потому вопрос следует закрыть как слишком общий.